# Laravel redirect login page after incorret login

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Login form in navbar (as dropdown menus). And when a user gives incorrect login, laravel should redirect back page.

I want to if user incorrect login , laravel redirect route("login") to main login form page.

I change RedirectIfAuthenticated.php but not working

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/');
    }
    return redirect()->route("login");
    return $next($request);
}
```

As result I getting error:

> To many redirects

How change error login after redirect login page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function `sendFailedLoginResponse()` which is called from `login()` function of `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` file. This file is included in `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController`. So you can change the redirection by using these files.

Answer (score 0):

You are awesome. Thank you.

I override method ;

```
public function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    return redirect()->route("login")->withErrors([
        $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
    ]);
}
```